# Sorting duplicates in a Stack algorithm (Java)

Tags: java, stack

I need help figuring out an algorithm for this problem (coding in java):

Write a method that takes a Stack of integers in ascending order and takes all duplicate integers and puts them at the back of the Stack, while keeping the ascending order.
For Example:
{1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8} becomes {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7, 7}
Note:
You cant use an iterator or a for each loop. You can only use the push(), pop(), isEmpty(), and size(). You must also use only one temporary Stack to solve the problem.

This isn't for homework or anything. It was on a test and I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Well.. then its time for you to think...

Comment: Well in general rearranging items in a stack is a no-no. But anyway, pop each element then add a counter with an if statement should solve this problem of yours. Assuming I have understood this well formulated question

Comment: @user2472706 - there is no 'general rule' that says you shouldn't rearrange items in a stack. It may not be the most efficient approach, but that doesn't mean that it's a no-no. Optimizing should be the last step in the process, not the first.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is wildly inefficient, and may not work correctly for edge cases, this solves for your test data and should be a good starting point.

I recommend debugging through it step by step to understand how it works.

```
public void solve(final Stack<Integer> stack) {

    // any stack with 2 or less items will already be in the solved order by definition
    if(stack.size() <= 2) {
        return;
    }

    Stack<Integer> tempStack = new Stack<Integer>();

    boolean isInCorrectOrder = false;
    do {

        // first, reverse the order
        while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
            tempStack.push(stack.pop());
        }

        // now pop the first item
        int currentItem = tempStack.pop();
        stack.push(currentItem);

        boolean foundDuplicate = false;
        // while the temp stack still has items
        while(!tempStack.isEmpty()) {
            // pop the next item
            int nextItem = tempStack.pop();

            // if the next item is the same then put it at the end of the stack after all the other elements
            if(nextItem == currentItem) {
                foundDuplicate = true;
                while(!tempStack.isEmpty()) {
                    stack.push(tempStack.pop());
                }
                stack.push(nextItem);
            } else if(nextItem < currentItem) {    // else if the next item is lower then we have reached the end of the main set of items
                stack.push(nextItem);
                while(!tempStack.isEmpty()) {
                    stack.push(tempStack.pop());
                }
                isInCorrectOrder = true;
            } else {    // elsejust push this item and pop the next one
                stack.push(nextItem);
                currentItem = nextItem;
            }
        }
        // if we did not find a duplicate, then the stack is in the correct order 
        if(!foundDuplicate) {
            isInCorrectOrder = true;
        }

    } while(!isInCorrectOrder);
}
```